# SaveFileDialog not getting opened in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, savefiledialog

I have created an application in visual studio 2010 using C#.net.
In that application I am generating MS-Word report...
For that I have used **SaveFileDialog** for saving that documnet to a particular location..
Initally it was woking fine...But from some days my **SaveFileDialog** window is not getting opened on my system.
Same code is working on other machines without any problem.
Things I have done to fix this problem :

1. Uninstall VS 2010 and reinstall it.
2. Installed VS 2012

But that problem is still there.
P.S. I have Windows 7 O.S. 64-bit

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm almost positive it has nothing to do with your VS installation, since you're not saving the file from it, but rather from your application. It would help if you showed the relevant code.  You mentioned that it works well on some machines, but not others... confirm that all of the appropriate libraries are on the target machines and the .NET framework installed meets the minimum requirement.  This is a very broad question, so you'll have to give us more information.

Comment: Thanx for your prompt reply.... SaveFileDialog mySaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
 mySaveFileDialog.DefaultExt = "*.doc"; //this is my code....it is working on all other PC's but not mine.Actually few days before there was no such issue...but suddenly SaveFileDialog stop working...i have checked all the requirements, .net framework version(4.0)..all the things are correct...but still that problem is there....plz tell me if any solution...

Answer (score 0):

`SaveFileDialog` will only operate if it is used from a thread set to single-threaded-apartment.

Ensure that the thread you are using to display it is set to that mode.

If you are calling it from the `Main()` thread, ensure that `Main()` is marked with the `[STAThread]` attribute like this:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main()
{
```

Comment: I don't think this behavior would differ from one machine to another?  Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this also caught by VS during compiling?

Comment: @B.K. No, it's not caught during compiling. Later versions of Visual Studio will show an error during a debugging session, but not otherwise. I'm not sure if VS2010 displays an error during a debugging session though. I'm not sure if other versions of the operating system will give different behaviour - but this is certainly the behaviour you get on Windows 7 if the thread apartment model is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, VS 2013 threw the exception during debugging. However, my assumption is that the machines he's using all run Windows 7 per his original post, so if there is an STA threading issue, it should have been apparent on all of them and not just some cases?  Not sure if he's able to debug on one of those client machines that's causing the error, but that would probably be a good idea... or at least record the exception, if there are any.